# Tagging docker containers with azure pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

I have a multistage YAML Azure pipeline. I tag my images based on the build ID. This works well until a job fails and I need to rerun it.

On the rerun I get a newly incremented build Id so it no longer references same docker image used in the original run.

`$(Build.BuildId)`

Is there anyway around this?

Comment: just to clarify, I want to rerun any stage of the job with the original buildId when it failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-running job or stage doesn't change `Build.BuildId`. I checked this using below pipeline. However if you want to run whole pipeline for the same build id you my try to use runtime paramaters and provide a tagName on your own (like below):

```yaml
parameters:
- name: tagName
  type: string
  default: ' '

trigger: none
pr: none

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'


stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: A
    steps:
    - pwsh: |
        $tagName = '$(Build.BuildId)'
        if('${{ parameters.tagName }}' -ne ' ') {
          $tagName = '${{ parameters.tagName }}'
        }
        echo $tagName

  - job: B
    steps:
    - bash: echo "B"

- stage: B
  jobs:
  - job: A
    steps:
    - pwsh: |
        $tagName = '$(Build.BuildId)'
        if('${{ parameters.tagName }}' -ne ' ') {
          $tagName = '${{ parameters.tagName }}'
        }
        echo $tagName
    - bash: exit 1

  - job: B
    steps:
    - bash: echo "B"
```

Comment: Thank you. You are 100% correct. Rerunning a job from the pipeline preserves the build number.

Answer (score 2):

You could expand stage and rerun the stage, this won't change the buildId:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I never knew this option existed. It's exactly what I was looking for